# Could SDL be used to target Xbox 360?

Tags: 2d, xna, xbox360

We're looking at developing a 2D game that could target Xbox 360.  Ideally, we'd also like to submit the game via the XNA program so that gamers could try out the game over Xbox Live.  We really love the fact that SDL is cross-platform.

Is writing a 2D game in SDL and then also targeting Xbox 360 possible, and if so how difficult might it be?

Comment: If you're looking to write a 2D game in XNA (a good choice), and you're concerned about being cross-platform, I recommend looking at SilverSprite: http://silversprite.codeplex.com/ (and various other, similar libraries). XNA is not as platform-locked as you might think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create creator club games on the Xbox 360 you have to use the XNA framework which in strictly C# .NET and even with that it must be managed C#.

Managed code allows .NET to handle all garbage collection and does not allow for use of pointers.

Yet another issues is XNA uses DirectX while SDL uses OpenGL.  SDL is written in C which is unmanaged, and even with C# bindings to SDL it will still be considered unmanaged code to a C# project.

There are many reasons that creator club games are limited to managed code, some of the main reasons are for security and stability.

Unfortunately what you want to do just isn't possible.

Comment: No, the reason CC games are limited to C# is to push their platform. Most AAA Xbox titles are plain ol' C/C++.

Comment: Allowing anyone to execute C/C++ code on the Xbox 360 could allow for huge console instability.

If you have an official Development Kit you can execute native C/C++ code on the 360.

Comment: @coderanger Sorry dude, but if I could down vote a comment, I would. The use of .NET in the CC is for security reasons and to allow for a clean sandbox while still allowing them to use the COM based DirectX without issue (something Java can't really do).

Sure, they have a vested interest in .NET, but that's not the reason they limited CC games to use it.

Comment: Then why does my devkit not also only run C#?

Comment: Because Development Kits are not given to everyone, and even still all 360 games have mandatory testing(for a fee) by Microsoft before they are allowed to be published.

Even patches have a mandatory testing fee from Microsoft before they can be released.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about the Creator Club and/or XBLI games, no. They have to built entirely with XNA (and I think C# specifically, might have relaxed that to include C++ now though).